# Keycloak API not actually searching users for realm

Tags: api, keycloak

Trying to call the keycloak API to query users and getting mixed results. If I query the Master realm I can get all users and search for a user using `username=foo` but if I try and do the same thing with a different realm I can get *all* the users but adding the `username=foo` query string also results in all the users coming back, and in some cases the user I searched will be at the top of the list, other times it wont be. Furthermore I can user `users/count?username=foo` to get a count of 1 from Master *and* certain other realms but some realms (again where I can return all users) show a count of 0 for the specified user.

I've looked all over for how the permissions work and I can't find anything that's helped.

I get a token for the user in Master and want to query all the realms with that. It's an admin account. I did try adding a user in the realm and authenticating with that but when I called the API I got a 403 forbidden error.

Can someone please advise what settings might be causing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible reasons.

1 short master Token expires time
2 not using admin-cli in master when get the token
3 not give a user filter in GET URI

you can extend more time during debugging
[image]

Using admin-cli and assign token variable in Postman when get the token
[image]

Add foo parameter filter by user name in GET URI
[image]

You needs to assign environment variable (I am using variable instead of array due to can't use array in  URI)
[image]

this is result of assign variable
[image]

Then you can get the foo user all of realms but it is hard code (no way to using GET API call in Postman)

I tested with three realms, two has foo user, one is not.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately it isn't any of these things. For requests to different realms I use more or less the same query, I only change the realm. My postman request retrieves a new token from the master realm each time so the token is not expiring, the user filter is present and the same across all requests, and the admin-cli property is also present. The issue is that when I query any realm other than master - the user query is not actually running (or not running properly) and all users are being returned. When I run the same query on master I get the user I asked for.

Comment: @Adamon, I tested Keycloak 18.0.0 and made three realms (third_ream, test realm and Second_realm) ,using  GET with Query param ({{keycloak_url}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm2/3/4}}/users?username=foo)
and master token(just single get, not every time if switch realm).
It should be works as same as my attached images.
If still not work, can you attached your not working Postman screen and your steps for reproduce it my self?

Comment: looking at the data I can see that the difference between the "searchable" and "unsearchable" users is that the "unsearchable" ones are federated users from an existing database. Do you know about this? So if a user is created via the admin portal it is searchable and if its federated then any search is returning every user that is federated. Do you know why this might be and why these users aren't indexed the same way. The realm differences were a red herring as it is because all users on master are manually created but users in realms are from existing databases.

Comment: I tested with Docker image openldap (osixia/openldap:1.5.0) and LDAP gui (osixia/phpldapadmin:0.9.0) for federation of Keycloak in local. it can import users from openldap into Keycloak in specific realm. And that foo user get API works too.
I think first, you needs to address all user import into Keycloack. It is not a API issue.

Comment: Hmm, I have found that using "search" as the query to mimic the search functionality of the portal works to some extent. It successfully searches federated users but in this case it matches the search term across username, email, first name, last name. So it's still not as useful as just "username=foo" as its bringing a valid wider result set back. If you have any idea about the import and how that might be affecting it please let me know but i cant see what could be wrong. Thanks for all your help so far. You have been very thorough and informative.

Comment: Without see the your problem, how to reproduce it and fix? It will help to any screen capture your symptom. Can you update your question with detail screen capture?
I just test it self as close as you mention. 
My additional comment in here, Can you success "Test authentication" button in LDAP federation? and if click "Synchronize all users" in federation in Keycloak , the popup screen say "Success! Sync of users finished successfully. 0 imported users, xxx updated users"? and finally In the users lookup in specific realms, can search foo as username. If not you makes a wrong configuration.