# Spring Boot Keycloak Access Token cannot work (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, keycloak

I have a problem about getting **login user info** after getting **access token** value from login process.

After I get **access token** value, I set it into **access token** field of **OAuth 2.0** under **Authorization** in **Postman**.

Next, I make a request to this url `http://localhost:9000/api/v1/users/info` but I get **500 Internal Server Error**.

My issues are shown below.

```
Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:8181/auth/realms/Client/.well-known/openid-configuration

java.lang.Exception: Not Found

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "this.input" is null
```

Here is my repository : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here is the image shown below.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Nice to share with your code. I got an error when I launch your docker-compose.yml
"service "database" refers to undefined volume db-data: invalid compose project" How to address it?

Comment: I addressed this problem. Adding this three lines at end of docker-compose.yml
volumes:
  db-data:  # Keycloack volume
      driver: local

Comment: Next problem appears in "api-gateway" Dockerfile when I build it.

#14 [build 5/7] RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve
#14 sha256:02fe326a66bc042dbbb7fd2a030ef77b77a7aa56407921a5144aeebb96e16c17
#14 0.317 /bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found
#14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./mvnw dependency:resolve]: exit code: 127

Comment: @BenchVue How can I fix the docker issue? I updated my repository.

Comment: I am using my docker-compose.yml. It using "keycloak:18.0.2-legacy" and "postgres" instead of your yml file.

Comment: @BenchVue Now, I want to test it. There is a problem in create User. How can I fix it? That's why I cannot get access token.

Comment: see the my answer for POST maser token. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72392669/keycloak-api-not-actually-searching-users-for-realm/72412466#72412466

Answer (score 0):

run docker-compose.yml file by "docker-compose up"

launch "localhost:8181" Click admin console.
[image]

login as administrator
(id: admin , password: admin)

[image]

You need to create "Client" realm in Keycloak after login by master admin
[image]

Select "Client" realm, then click Endpoints
[image]

Finally you can address
http://localhost:8181/auth/realms/Client/.well-known/openid-configuration
problem.
[image]

Comment: the issue is related with wrongly defined keycloak properties in the service. I already fixed it before your response I just wanted to thank you for your response, though.

Comment: No problem. It is cool idea to share with your repository of source code when ask something.

Comment: Is it possible to look through my link if you don't mind?

Comment: No problem, where is your link?

Comment: It is defined in the post.

Comment: what is it? I don't get it.

Comment: Here is my repository : Link